# Traverse to matching parens in Lispworks

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, parentheses, lispworks

Is this possible?  I haven't been able to find out how in the help or manuals.

Comment: Editor User Guide.  Editing Lisp Programs. Forms.
http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/EDUG-M/html/eduser-m-57.htm#pgfId-884090

Comment: @RainerJoswig I don't think this question is related with emacs. I suggest revert the edit.

Comment: @HenriqueJung: The LispWorks IDE provides an editor, which belongs to the class of Emacs editors. There are many editors like that, who share principles like UI with meta/control commands, modes, buffers, command layouts, movement, etc etc. If the general tag emacs is used to mean a specific editor, say GNU Emacs, then this would be wrong...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks for the clarification. But the description of the tag refers to GNU Emacs. Anyway I don't see a problem since LispWorks is emacs-like and I don't think we have a tag for that.

Comment: @HenriqueJung: tags might mean something slightly different based on context. Some communities occupy generic tags for their specialized meanings. In this case Emacs means a class of editor with a specific idea about commands/keymaps/modifiers and movements. Even though the keyboard commands are not fully the same, they share ideas. c-f, m-f, etc. for moving forward over various quantities (character, word, sentence, Lisp expressions, ...).

Answer (score 2):

C-M-Left and C-M-Right should jump the cursor to the previous and next SEXP in the LispWorks editor which really is an old version of emacs.